# Excel 2013 Chart Template Not Working

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, charts, templates

I've created a boxplot in Excel 2013, and have saved it as a chart template.

[Original boxplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGch4.png)

However, when I select identically formatted data, and create a new chart from that template, it comes out almost completely wrong. The horizontal and vertical axes get flipped for some reason, and only the bottom whiskers are shown; the rest of the plots are non-existent.

[Unedited template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J53OY.png)

Once I flip the axes back to where they should be, the bottom whiskers are maintained, but the rest of plots lose all other formatting.

[Template after switching horiz & vert axes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3AU2.png)

This worked without issue in Excel 2010. Is it just a bug in 2013? Are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

From everything I can tell, it's a bug. However, I have found somewhat of a workaround.

In the new data, if you insert a new stacked bar chart and switch the axes, Excel will finally realize that this is the right type of data for a boxplot template, and will properly format it.

So there are a couple of extra steps you have to go through, but it still saves time overall to use the template.